# Updating Angular2 variable using Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

ALERT: Newbie to Angular2
I have the following code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
            <button (click)="ClickMe()">Button</button>`
})

export class AppComponent
{
  name:string;
  ClickMe(event : event) :void {
    var source = new Observable((observer: any) => {
      observer.next(42);
    });
    source.subscribe(function (x : any) {
    name = x;
    alert(x);
    });

  }
}
```

my alert does pops up, but the view doesnt change in other words, I don't get the "Hello 42" , I still see just "Hello"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
  ClickMe(event : Event) :void {
    var source = new Observable((observer: any) => {
      observer.next(42);
    });
    source.subscribe(x => {
    this.name = x;
    alert(x);
    });

  }
```

Comment: Okay, it works for me when I tested it, the view changes :)

Comment: Forked the plunker provided by 5313M above, and as can see it works :) https://plnkr.co/edit/Z8bZPzKm0zZ0q4Mcm1g7?p=preview But I see you accepted my answer, so good that you figured it out! :)

Comment: ok, this works, thank you, quick question, why this works: 
source.subscribe(x => {...}       but not this: 
source.subscribe(function (x) {...} ?

Comment: Someone smarter can probably answer this better. I only know that with `function (x)...` you loose the ability of using `this`, and `this.name` is what you, in this case, want to use to bind it to your view. Hopefully someone else can explain better...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vaPoei1mZhKXx0026pDg?p=preview) , it is working.
should point on the object's name by `this.name` and there is no need for a the `function` while *subscribing*.

Comment: Your example doesnt work, after clicking the button, the "Hello" doesnt change to "Hello 42", its the same issue I am inquiring about.

Comment: Ah , Ok it was not clear what you want .. thought it is an issue with observables .. i'll update the answer

Comment: @Pacman the plnkr is updated with some cleanups .. (slightly different from AJT_82) & it is working :-)